# I once asked a question about printer

Tags: discussion

I provided specs. I said price must be at most $1k, and I want a refillable ink tank.

The question is closed.

And I have no idea why.

Some says it's not specific enough. I don't think there are many devices that qualify. My other even less specific questions are accepted.

Would you please enlighten me?

[Question link](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2459/recommend-me-with-a-wireless-printer) (deleted; requires 2k rep)

I found a sample http://www.epson.com/cgi-bin/Store/jsp/Landing/ecotank-super-tank-printers.do

However, I can't find those printers on Indonesian's online shops and that doesn't seem like the most popular model.

Actually modifiable ones are fine too.

I tried to find in google.

I use words, wireless printer refillable ink. Is that how I should search for it?

In Indonesia, we already have refillable printers. What we do is we buy a printer and then we modified it. I am thinking of getting a refillable ones on the get go.

Comment: Link? Few people are going to know what question you are asking about.

Comment: I don't see a question about a printer in your account history. Please link it.

Comment: It;s deleted so I can't link to it. They said there are plenty. I only found 4 and all are not suitable for me because they don't show up on tokopedia.com and lazada.co.id

Comment: Some other details to add to your question that may help: what you intend to use it for; a specific price range (e.g. "under $40"); examples of specific printers you've already considered and rejected, and *why* those printers were unsatisfactory; why you want to limit your search to a specific web site (maybe we know of another site that would also meet your needs).

Answer (score 1):

The question was closed as too broad

[image: Too Broad]

As one of the close voters, I stand by my initial vote. You left four enumerated criteria:

- Ink must be refillable
- Wireless
- Scanner would be nice
- "Cheap as possible"

I left you the following comment:

> I voted to close this as a broad question. Your requirements are a good start, but they still leave you with a wide variety of wireless printers to choose from. Have you performed any searches yourself and ruled out specific printers? If so, what and why? That will help us narrow down a list of options. Additionally, a budget for your printer would be helpful too.

To which you responded:

> I updated the question. I've heard an epson printer satisfy this category.

Your update was to put the "cheap as possible" requirement. This knocked it into the Reopen queue, where it [failed](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/2020) to garner the votes to reopen. Your update doesn't address the point I was making in the comments. Your requirements are very broad and if we were to go perform a general search for you (which isn't what we do), we'd get back a number of results you've possibly looked at already. Your comment mentions that Epson has printers that may meet your criteria, but you don't mention why you've reject those. If *we* find Epson printers, or someone has a user testimonial about an Epson printer, it's a waste of both their time and your time, because it seems you've rejected them already, but we don't know why.

Finally, the question was deleted automatically by the system on April 18th.

[image: Deleted]

It was deleted because it met the [criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/186281) of an `RemoveAbandonedClosed` question:

> #### If the question was closed more than 9 days ago, and ...
>
> - not closed as a duplicate
> - has a score of 0 or less
> - is not locked
> - has no answers with a score > 0
> - has no accepted answer
> - has no pending reopen votes
> - has not been edited in the past 9 days
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted. These are "abandoned closed", and show as `RemoveAbandonedClosed`:

Comment: I hear an epson printer meet the criteria because one of the sellers told me that. I wanted to confirm that from the pro in hardware stackexchange. I already forget. You said there are many. Please name 1.

Comment: @JimThio There's no need to name one; I can tell from the requirements that there will be lots of matching results.

Comment: such as? What? Tell me the best 1 or 2?

Comment: @JimThio, this meta question isn't a round about way to get your answer. The question was closed. As the OP, you have the ability to edit the question and get it reopened, but you need to make that effort

Comment: How do I do so? It's already deleted. I will add that lazada.co.id requirement?

Comment: [Edit](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/posts/2459/edit) the question and flag for reopening. Look at the notes I made above. Adding a single link isn't going to get it through the reopen queue.

Comment: @JimThio I've undeleted the post but I haven't reopened it; I'd like to see what community opinion on it is.